# Shortest weight constrained path to Partition reduction

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, np-complete

I am trying to prove NP-completness of a shortest weight constrained path problem. I have read multiple papers, but for love of god, cannot figure out how to show a reduction of this to partition problem.

The question is given for each edge, a weight w and length l, show that for an undirected graph, the problem of finding a path such that sum of weights on the path < W and sum of lenghths of the path < L where, L and W are constants given to us in the problem.

I looked at Garey and Johnson which just states that problem is NP complete and doesn't provide a way to prove, or a reduction.

Comment: This question is more suitable for cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: No, it's more suitable for cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have a solution but writing it down here is so much pain because I can't use LaTeX. If you ask on cs.stackexchange.com I can post the answer there.